# SQLAlchemy Error sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1193, "Unknown system variable 'transaction_isolation'")

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am using SQLAlchemy==2.0.9 and pymysql1.0.3 .I am using MYSQL5.7
I constantly get the error transaction_isolation as unsupported system variable.

I have no choice to upgrade MYSQL and i have to use SQLAlchemy . Which is the right version of SQLAlchemy that will work for me or is there a way to overcome this error

I tried show variables and i see tx_isolation in mysql db. I tried to set transaction_isolation as variable it gave same 1193 error

Please help

I tried show variables and i see tx_isolation in mysql db. I tried to set transaction_isolation as variable it gave same 1193 error

Please help

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `transaction_isolation` was added in [MySQL-5.7.20](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-20.html) released on 2017-10-16.

This would appear to mean you're using a version older than this so you need to use `@@tx_isolation` as a variable. [sqlachemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/41cfe44b5e5806b3d3b13949e41dbb347bfa29e1) does a version based retrieval in all the 2.0 versions.